# How to load paragraphs fields in hook_form_alter to disallow access?

Tags: 8, hooks, paragraphs

I have a field inside a paragraph referenced in an taxonomy term.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter()
 */
function custom_general_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'taxonomy_term_application_category_form':
        $entity = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
        kint($entity);
        break;
  }
}
```

Inside Paragraph field named field_test_para, 
I have a text field named field_text,
how can I fetch array structure of field_text in order to hide the 
field_text and how can disallow access to the text field. So far, I 
have managed to get the taxonomy entity and looking on how I can fetch 
paragraph entity and then alter the #access parameter of text field 
within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'taxonomy_term_application_category_form':
      // Hide the Button Text as its value is autopopulated from the term name.
      if (isset($form['field_test_para']['widget'][0]['subform']['field_test_para2']['widget'][0]['subform']['field_button_text'])) {
        $form['field_test_para']['widget'][0]['subform']['field_test_para2']['widget'][0]['subform']['field_button_text'] = FALSE;
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a preprocess paragraphs function which will target it more easily

```
function mymodule_preprocess_paragraph__myparagraph(&$vars)
{
    if ($vars['view_mode'] == 'full') {
        $parag = $vars['paragraph'];
        if (SOME LOGIC HERE){
        unset($vars['content']['myfield']);
        $var['field_removed']=true;
    }
}
```

The key point is to replace `__myparagraph` with the id of your paragraph

This example show you:

- How to access the paragraph object `$parag = $vars['paragraph'];`
- How to handle your logic only for a view mode `($vars['view_mode'] == 'full')`
- Remove a field `unset($vars['content']['myfield']);`
- You can test the variable `field_removed` in your twig template to not run the code to display the field (optional)

Oups, it looks like you are asking to alter a paragraph's form...
For this you can use `hook_field_widget_paragraphs_form_alter`

```
function maymodule_field_widget_paragraphs_form_alter(&$element, FormStateInterface &$form_state, $context)
{
    switch ($element['#paragraph_type']) {
        case 'myparagraphs':
            $term = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
            //Check if paragraph is inside a form term
            if($term && ($term->getEntityTypeId()=='taxonomy_term')){
                $voc=$term->bundle();
                //Check if it is the desired voc
                if($voc=='my_voc'){
                    //unset($element['subform']['field_to_be hidded']); //to hide only one field
                    $element=[]; //to hide all the form
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: I am using the paragraph in an taxonomy entity

Comment: hook_field_widget_paragraphs_form_alter is available in your use case...

Comment: Hi @Baud, but I am using paragraph inside taxonomy term form and I need to hide it only for paragraph used in a particular taxonomy , if its used in node form it needs to be visible ?

Comment: I have updated my answer...